# Meaning of 'Closed Form'

Tags: logistic-regression, terminology

Here's an excerpt from a paper explaining Logistic Regression. What does 'Closed Form' mean in this context? Please explain in simple terms. The definitions online are confusing.

> **Gradient of Log Likelihood:**
> Now that we have a function for
> log-likelihood, we simply need to choose the values of theta that
> maximize it. Unfortunately, if we try just setting the derivative
> equal to zero, we’ll quickly get frustrated: there’s no **closed form**
> for the maximum. However, we can find the best values of theta by
> using an optimization algorithm. The optimization algorithm we will
> use requires the partial derivative of log likelihood with respect to
> each parameter.

Comment: Have you looked at the answers on [the following question on the cross validated stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/70848)?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Closed-FormSolution.html